# What is an adjective or concept that describes a combination of ability and diligence?

Tags: adjectives

Is there an adjective that describes someone who has both a high degree of natural ability and diligence, as opposed to someone who is naturally able but not very hard working or vice-versa?

I thought of adjectives such as 'competent' or 'capable', but I am wondering if there is another one that captures this sense of having both attributes better?

Comment: I'm thinking "masterful", because masterful usually means both ability and taking pride in one's work (doing so would likely make you diligent). But masterful may be over the top. Also "masterful" doesn't emphasise what you did in your question, namely natural ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adept** is both an adjective and a noun that mean *skilled* or *expert*, but also implies longterm study.

> He is *adept* at juggling.
>
> She studied the ancient texts for years and is now an *adept*.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/adept